# Django DatabaseError when deleting any record from admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

i have asked a question about manytomanyfield here which i solved but now a new problem is raised as,

```
DatabaseError at /admin/myapp/photo/8/delete/

relation "woek_gallery_photos" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "woek_gallery_photos" WHERE "photo_id" IN ...
```

i know why this problem raises but i dont know how to. i have one Photo model which has relation with both Group model and Gallery model. when i add an image from Gallery it works good but as to deleting it, raises problem with Group about not having any relation...

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    ....
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='galleries', 
             verbose_name=_('Gallery'),
                                    null=True, blank=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='galleries', 
             verbose_name=_('Group'),
                                    null=True, blank=True, 
                                    through='through=GroupPhotos')

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name = "Browse", 
                              upload_to=myPath)
```

I appreciate your all helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means the join table for the relationship between `Photo` and `Gallery` is missing or was never created in the first place. If you haven't done so already run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

If that still doesn't work, create the table manually. You can run:

```
python manage.py sqlall yourapp
```

to get the proper SQL to use. Look for the lines where it creates `woek_gallery_photos` and copy that bit. Then run:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

And paste it at the prompt. Hit enter, and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank u. `./manage.py syncdb` hadnt added foreignkey relation with it so i added with manually altering table... so it works.

Answer (score 1):

`relation "woek_gallery_photos" does not exist` means the TABLE "woek_gallery_photos" doesn't exist. Did you forget to run syncdb after creating the Photo model?